# Invalid column name on database table

Tags: sql, indexing

Some help here pls. I cant figure out why this error.

Invalid column name 'Blogs_Id1'.
Invalid column name 'Blogs_Id1'.
Invalid column name 'Blogs_Id1'. 
  Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid column name 'Blogs_Id1'.
Invalid column name 'Blogs_Id1'.
Invalid column name 'Blogs_Id1'.

Source Error:

Line 84: 
Line 85:         @{
Line 86:             foreach (var comment in Model.Comments) {...

Here is my model

```
 public class Blogs
{
    public  int Id { get; set; }
    [Required, Display(Name = "Title"), MaxLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0}  should be 100   characters maximum"), MinLength(10, ErrorMessage = "The {0} is too short!")]
    public string BlogTitle { get; set; }
    [Required, Display(Name ="Post description"),StringLength(500,ErrorMessage ="{0} too large. Should be maximum of 400 characters"),AllowHtml]
    public string Description { get; set; }
    [Required,MinLength(50,ErrorMessage ="The {0} should be a minimum of 50 characters"),AllowHtml]

    public string Body { get; set; }
    public DateTime PostDate { get; set; }
    public string Author { get; set; }
    public string PostImage { get; set; }
    public virtual  ICollection<Comments> Comments { get; set; }
} 

 public class Comments
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(400, ErrorMessage = "Too many characters in comments. Please limit it to 400 characters"), Required]
    public string Comment { get; set; }

    public int Blogs_Id { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my database code

```
CreateTable(
            "dbo.Blogs",
            c => new
                {
                    Id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                    BlogTitle = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 100),
                    Description = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 500),
                    Body = c.String(nullable: false),
                    PostDate = c.DateTime(nullable: false),
                    Author = c.String(),
                    PostImage = c.String(),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id);

        CreateTable(
            "dbo.Comments",
            c => new
                {
                    Id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                    Username = c.String(),
                    Date = c.DateTime(nullable: false),
                    Comment = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 400),
                    Blogs_Id = c.Int(),

                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.Blogs", t => t.Blogs_Id)
            .Index(t => t.Blogs_Id);
```

The Blogs and Comments tables successfully created. however, when I want to access the post detail where a I intend to display the comments too, the error above keeps coming.

for reference, here is the view code (The comments part)

```
@{
        foreach (var comment in Model.Comments) { 

    <div class="media">

        <div class="media-body">
            <img src="~/images/user.png" width="200" height="200" style="margin: 0 15px 15px 0; float:left" alt="user" title="@comment.Username" />
            <h4 class="media-heading">

                @comment.Username
                <small>@comment.Date.ToLongDateString()</small>
            </h4>
            @comment.Comment
        </div> 
    </div>
    }}
```

Thanks for help

Comment: Are you using Entity Framework?

Comment: Can you show us `CreateTable`? It looks like a custom wrapper around `.ToTable` and the [Fluent Configuration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696568(v=vs.113).aspx)

Comment: You're receiving a SQL exception, presumably Blogs_Id1 is not a valid column for the table you are querying. Check the database to model mapping for whatever framework you're using.

Comment: @Dan yes! the database code above is a database migration script generated by Ef.  however, when the code was generated initially, the column Blogs_Id1 was automatically included in the script as the foreign key constraint  but I modified it to use the column Blogs_Id.

Answer (score 0):

According to your Blogs create string, the column name for the Foreign key should be ID. Not Blogs_ID.

ForeignKey("dbo.Blogs", t => t.Blogs_Id) -> ForeignKey("dbo.Blogs", t => t.Id)